# Where can I find the release notes for QGIS patches?

Tags: qgis

I found release notes only for major.minor versions and cannot locate information for patches. For instance, there are release notes for 3.34, but no information for 3.34.3. Similarly, there are notes for 3.28, but none for 3.28.15.

https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelogs.html provides information for major.minor releases. Could you please advise on where I can find release notes for patches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to create change logs for such a big project. I think you can read the commits information on [github](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/releases) by clicking on each release and [3.34.3](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/compare/final-3_34_2%5E...final-3_34_3) in particular.